# How to read Read an RGB image as grayscale image using keras data generator?

Tags: keras

[image][image]**strong text**
I want to read image (1) whose pixel values range is 0-50, using keras generator , but when I set color_mode=‘grayscale’, or even ‘rgb’ it converts all values berween 0 and 1 as shown in figure (2). Which Arguments of ImageDataGenerator or flow_from_directory to be set so that I could get image (1) pixel values range from keras generator ?

Here is the code I am using

```
Data_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) #included in our dependencies
seed=2020
train_left=Data_datagen.flow_from_directory('train_left/train/',target_size=(384,512), color_mode='grayscale',batch_size=2,shuffle=True,seed=seed)

img=train_left[100][0]
img=img[0]
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img[:,:,:])
```

Comment: Can you add code that you tried as well as the output you received and the expected output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pixel values are from 0-50, it already will be a strange output since RGB and grayscale both expect values on the range 0-255 for each channel. It is likely that the reason your generator is doing this, is because that is the desired way to handle images in deep learning--scaling to [0, 1]. If you do not want to rescale it you should share code so we can see what exactly you are doing.

Without code, I would suspect you need to change this value in the generator.

```
rescale=1./255
```